# ¿Cómo validar si varios inputs tipo radio están vacíos al mismo tiempo?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy intentando validar que estén marcados inputs tipo radio a la vez, cuando el usuario precione el boton de enviar, entonces si un radio esta sin marcar que le salga una alerta.

Lo que tengo es esto:

función jq:

```
function submitSw_Sesiones_ses2_act1(){
    event.preventDefault();

        alert(document.getElementById("g").checked);
    if (document.getElementById("g").checked== false){
        alert("Acepta los terminos y condiciones del servicio");
        document.getElementById("<strong>aceptocondiciones_chk</strong>").focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

Al parecer si me lo esta haciendo pero solamente con el primer radio, es decir si marco el primer radio, me marca un true aun que estén desmarcados los demás.

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>Desechar todos los cigarros, limpiar los ceniceros, deshacerse de cerillos y encendedores. Pensar en cualquier imagen negativa acerca del cigarro.</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="radio" id="g"  name="recomendacion_1" value="Si" required>&nbsp;Si &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" id="g"  name="recomendacion_1" value="No" required>&nbsp;No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Adoptar una actitud positiva, tratar de concebirse como ex fumador.</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="radio" id="g"  name="recomendacion_2" value="Si" required>&nbsp;Si &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" id="g"  name="recomendacion_2" value="No" required>&nbsp;No</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás asignando el mismo ID a todos los campos; los [ID deben ser únicos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). `document.getElementById()` te va a devolver siempre solo un elemento, por lo general, el primero.

Te sugiero usar [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) donde puedes seleccionar elementos por atributos HTML, como nombre de campo y si está marcado.

- Para buscar por el atributo de nombre, usas el selector `[name="nombre_del_campo"]`
- Para que obtenga solo el que está marcado, agregas `:checked`

Si el radio no tiene una opción marcada, `querySelector()` va a devolver un valor nulo y eso es lo que puedes usar para validar.

```js
function submitSw_Sesiones_ses2_act1(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // Obtener valor del cada radio, por nombre y estado
    let recom1 = document.querySelector('[name="recomendacion_1"]:checked');
    let recom2 = document.querySelector('[name="recomendacion_2"]:checked');
    
    // Si alguno no fue marcado, la variable será nula
    // Podría ser: recom1 === null || recom2 === null
    // Pero esto funciona igual, null es considerado falso en la comparación
    if(!recom1 || !recom2) {
        console.log('Debes seleccionar una opción en cada recomendación.');
        return false;
    }
    // Los dos radios fueron marcados
    console.log(recom1.value, recom2.value);
    return true;
}

// Asignar evento al botón
document.querySelector('#btn-submit').addEventListener('click', submitSw_Sesiones_ses2_act1);
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Desechar todos los cigarros, limpiar los ceniceros, deshacerse de cerillos y encendedores. Pensar en cualquier imagen negativa acerca del cigarro.</td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="recomendacion_1" value="Si" required>&nbsp;Si &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="recomendacion_1" value="No" required>&nbsp;No</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Adoptar una actitud positiva, tratar de concebirse como ex fumador.</td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="recomendacion_2" value="Si" required>&nbsp;Si &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="recomendacion_2" value="No" required>&nbsp;No</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- Agregado solo para probar -->
<button id="btn-submit">Enviar</button>
```

Prueba haciendo clic en el botón, primero sin marcar los radios, verás que aparece el mensaje de error en la consola. Ya cuando marcas los dos y vuelve a hacer clic en el botón, puedes ver los valores seleccionados.